# Soldidity HTML script does nothing

Tags: html, solidity, web3js

I am trying to make a basic solidity contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
contract sample {
 string public name = "NAME";
function set(string _name) {
   name = _name;
}
function get() constant returns (string) {
  return name;
}
}
```

I am using this html file to let me input into the contract:

```
    <html>
 <head>
  <title>Blockchain</title>
 </head>
 <body class="container">
  <h3>Blockchain</h3>
   <div class="tab-content">
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="blockchain">
   <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <input type="text" class="text form-control" value="TEXT HERE">
      <button class="set btn btn-primary">Set Value</button>
   </div>
  <h3> 2. Get the current value</h3>
   <div class="form-group">
   <div>
     current value is <span class="value"></span>
   </div>
    <button class="get btn btn-primary">Get Value</button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
</body>
  <script src="web3.js-develop/dist/web3.js">
    var Web3 = require(‘web3’);
    var web3 = new Web3();
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
    var sampleContractABI = [{"constant": true,"inputs": [],"name": "name","outputs": [  {   "name": "",   "type": "string"  }],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "view","type": "function"},{"constant": false,"inputs": [  {    "name": "_name",    "type": "string"  }],"name": "set","outputs": [],"payable": false,"stateMutability": "nonpayable","type": "function"},{  "constant": true,  "inputs": [],  "name": "get",  "outputs": [    {      "name": "",      "type": "string"    }  ],  "payable": false,  "stateMutability": "view",  "type": "function"}];
    var sampleContract = web3.eth.contract(sampleContractABI);
    var sampleContractInstance = sampleContract.at(0xF215eaC1b9E82DeF712B6889a0adB24fAf216250);
    $("#blockchain button.set").click(function() {
  var value = $("#blockchain input.text").val();
  var params = {
    gas: 40000,
    from: 
  };
  SimpleStorage.sendTransaction.set(value, params);
  });
  $("#blockchain button.get").click(function() {
  var value = SimpleStorage.get.call();
  $("#blockchain .value").html(value);
  });
  </script>
</html>
```

But when I enter into the box and hit Set value, then wait a little bit and hit get value, nothing ever happens. Can anyone instruct me on what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Do you see an error in the browser console? I would expect `SimpleStorage.sendTransaction` to be undefined, but that would generate an error message.

Comment: @smarx I get nothing in the console.

Comment: Oh, looks like you have all your code inside a `script` tag with a `src` attribute? I'm not sure that code will run at all.

Comment: It's also outside of the `body` tag. I'm not sure that's valid.

Comment: Try, inside the `body` tag: `<script src="web3.js-develop/dist/web3.js"></script>` followed by `<script>var Web3 = require('web3');...</script>`. Also note that the quotes around `web3` are currently wrong. (`‘` vs. `'`)

Comment: @smarx Tried all that, didn't work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? You still don't see any output on the console? Have you tried explicitly adding a line like `console.log("hello world")`?

Comment: @smarx Sorry, I didn't properly read you comment about <script src="...></script> and moving those into the body. After doing that I am getting an error. It is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } on line 33. And I added those console.logs and I am getting nothing in the console.

Comment: Well, fix your syntax error before continuing. :-) If you share your latest code and indicate which line is line 33, someone can help, but presumably the error will be obvious.

Comment: BTW, it won't be the only error... the code you shared has several problems, and only one (the one I first pointed out) is related to web3.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed it, only by rewriting the entire script.